# Routing traffic to virtual copy of network without namespaces

Tags: linux-kernel, routing, nftables

Given the following diagram, is it possible to route traffic through the linux kernel like this? I wish to simulate an exact copy of the devices outside of my "inner" network, with the same IP-ranges whilst enabling the inner and outer devices to communicate with each other without knowing that the other has the same IP as itself.

[image: Low-level description of network interfaces on machine]

For example: Device X on the "inside" contacts 192.168.3.5, this goes to the middleman-bridge and gets forwarded to device Y on the "outside" with IP 192.168.2.5. The response is then sent back to middleman, and sent to device X with IP 192.168.2.5.

I know that this is possible with network-namespaces and have a working simulation with that. However, I wish to avoid namespaces and instead use something like different routing tables for the different directions of traffic. Is this possible?

If I have understood it correctly, I cannot use NAT because of the duplicated IP-ranges. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Topology

We start by configuring the network interfaces on `middleman`. I'm assuming that either you're logged in on the system console or you have access via an interface that's not involved in either the `inner` or `outer` networks. For the purpose of this answer, we're going to assume that interface `middleman-eth0` on `middleman` is connected to the "inner" network and `middleman-eth1` is connected to the "outer" network. This gives us the following network topology:

[image: network topology diagram]

### Enable forwarding

We need to ensure that we have enabled packet forwarding on `middleman`:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And we should start with an empty netfilter configuration. Running `iptables-save` should produce no output.

### Interface configuration

For this to work, both `middleman-eth0` and `middleman-eth1` will have identical network configurations:

```
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev middleman-eth0
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev middleman-eth1
```

If you think that looks weird, you're right! At the moment, the routing table on `middleman` looks like this:

```
192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

That's not going to be particularly useful.

### VRF configuration

We're going to take advantage of Linux's support for "[virtual routing and forwarding](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/vrf.html)" ("VRF"). This allows us to create multiple isolated routing domains on a system, so that traffic coming in on `eth0` will see a different routing table than traffic coming in on `eth1`.

We first create the VRF interfaces:

```
ip link add vrf-inner type vrf table 100
ip link set vrf-inner up
ip link add vrf-outer type vrf table 200
ip link set vrf-outer up
```

These commands set up two VRF devices, associating each one with a specific routing table.

Next, we attach each of our physical interfaces to a VRF devices:

```
ip link set dev middleman-eth0 master vrf-inner
ip link set dev middleman-eth1 master vrf-outer
```

With these changes, the primary routing table is now empty:

```
middleman# ip route show
<no output>
```

In table 100 we see the rules associated with `middleman-eth0` (the "inner" network):

```
middleman# ip route show table 100
broadcast 192.168.2.0 dev middleman-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
local 192.168.2.1 dev middleman-eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.2.1
broadcast 192.168.2.255 dev middleman-eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

And in table 200 we see the rules for `middleman-eth1` (the "outer" network):

```
middleman# ip route show table 200
broadcast 192.168.2.0 dev middleman-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
local 192.168.2.1 dev middleman-eth1 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.2.1
broadcast 192.168.2.255 dev middleman-eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

At this point, we effectively have two disconnected networks that look like this:

[image: network topology showing isolated routing domains]

Hosts on the "inner" network can contact 192.168.2.1, and they will be talking to `middleman-eth0`. Hosts on the "outer" network can *also* contact 192.168.2.1, but they will be talking to `middleman-eth1`.

### In which the twain do meet

All that we need to do now is set up the mapping so that either side can use addresses from `192.168.3.0/24` to contact nodes on the other side.

First, we need to tell all the nodes that they route to the `192.168.3.0/24` network via `middleman`; that means on all the nodes, on both the "inner" and "outer" networks, we need:

```
ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.2.1
```

On `middleman`, we need to (a) map addresses in the `192.168.3.0/24` range into the `192.168.2.0/24` range and (b) ensure that when we route the connection we use the correct routing table. To accomplish (a) we can create some `NETMAP` rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.3.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.2.0/24
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.3.0/24
```

To accomplish (b), we'll first mark packets based on their ingress interface:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i middleman-eth0 -d 192.168.3.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i middleman-eth1 -d 192.168.3.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 200
```

And then use those marks to select a routing table:

```
ip rule add prio 100 fwmark 100 lookup 200
ip rule add prio 200 fwmark 200 lookup 100
```

Recall from earlier that table 100 has the rules for the "inner" network and table 200 has the rules for the "outer" network, so these rules say "for packets arriving on interface `middleman-eth0`, make a routing decision using the routing table associated with `middleman-eth1`", and vice-versa.

### Following the bouncing ball

With all this in place, if node `192.168.2.10` on the "inner" networks tries to ping `192.168.3.10`:

1. The packet gets routed to middleman because of the `192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.2.1` route entry
2. The packet arrives at `middleman-eth0`
3. The packet hits the `MANGLE` table `PREROUTING` chain and has the fwmark set to `100`
4. The packet hits the `NAT` table `PREROUTING` chain and has the destination mapped to `192.168.2.10`
5. The packet enters the routing subsystem, where it hits the `fwmark 100 lookup 200` rule
6. In routing table 200, it hits the `192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth1`, so the kernel will send it out device `middleman-eth1`
7. The packet hits the `NAT` table `POSTROUTING` chain, where it has its source mapped to `192.168.3.10`.
8. The packet arrives at the "outer" node with address `192.168.2.10`.
9. **...take a deep breath...**
10. The outer node sends a reply to `192.168.3.10`
11. The reply arrives at `middleman-eth1`
12. The reply hits the `MANGLE` table `PREROUTING` chain and has the fwmark set to `200`
13. The reply hits the `NAT` table `PREROUTING` chain and has the destination mapped to `192.168.2.10`
14. The reply enters the routing subsystem, where it hits the `fwmark 200 lookup 100` rule
15. In routing table 100, it hits the `192.168.2.0/24 dev middleman-eth0` rule, so the kernel will send it out device `middleman-eth0`
16. The reply hits the `NAT` table `POSTROUTING` chain, where it has its source mapped to `192.168.3.10`
17. The reply arrives at "inner" node `192.168.2.10`, which sees a reply to the request it initially sent out.

### Validation

If on "inner" node 0 (`192.168.2.10`) we attempt to ping "outer" node 0 using address `192.168.3.10`, running `tcpdump -nn -i any icmp` on inner node 0 shows:

```
07:01:58.125370 innernode0-eth0 Out IP 192.168.2.10 > 192.168.3.10: ICMP echo request, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
07:01:58.125533 innernode0-eth0 In  IP 192.168.3.10 > 192.168.2.10: ICMP echo reply, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
```

On `middleman` we see:

```
07:01:58.125440 middleman-eth0 In  IP 192.168.2.10 > 192.168.3.10: ICMP echo request, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
07:01:58.125459 middleman-eth1 Out IP 192.168.3.10 > 192.168.2.10: ICMP echo request, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
07:01:58.125514 middleman-eth1 In  IP 192.168.2.10 > 192.168.3.10: ICMP echo reply, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
07:01:58.125518 middleman-eth0 Out IP 192.168.3.10 > 192.168.2.10: ICMP echo reply, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
```

And on "outer" node 0 we see:

```
07:01:58.125489 outernode0-eth0 In  IP 192.168.3.10 > 192.168.2.10: ICMP echo request, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
07:01:58.125497 outernode0-eth0 Out IP 192.168.2.10 > 192.168.3.10: ICMP echo reply, id 12999, seq 1, length 64
```

So I think we have accomplished your goal!

---

I used [mininet](https://mininet.org) to test this configuration; you can find the complete sources for my test environment [here](https://github.com/larsks/unix-example-735931-1-1-nat). There is a video of this configuration in action [here](https://youtu.be/A_OdCsyAgUI).

### Update

As A.B. points out in comments, there is a problem with this configuration! By default, the kernel's connection tracking logic looks only at source/destination address and source/destination port. A connection from `innernode0` port 4000 to `outernode0` port 80 would appear to be the *same* connection as one in the opposite direction...that is, assuming that I have a webserver running on port 80 on all the nodes, these two commands:

```
innernode0# curl --local-port 4000 192.168.3.10
```

And:

```
outernode0# curl --local-port 4000 192.168.3.10
```

Would result in a single connection tracking entry on `middleman`:

```
middleman# conntrack  -L
tcp      6 118 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.2.10 dst=192.168.3.10 sport=4000 dport=80 src=192.168.2.10 dstroot@mininet-vm:/proc/net=192.168.3.10 sport=80 dport=4000 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

We to tell the conntrack subsystem how to differentiate this connections. We can do that by adding a pair of `CT` rules to the `PREROUTING` chain in the `RAW` table:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i middleman-eth0 -j CT --zone-orig 100
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i middleman-eth1 -j CT --zone-orig 200
```

With these rules in place, we now see two separate connections in the conntrack table:

```
middleman# conntrack -L
tcp      6 113 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.2.10 dst=192.168.3.10 sport=4000 dport=80 zone-orig=200 src=192.168.2.10 dst=192.168.3.10 sport=80 dport=40568 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
tcp      6 112 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.2.10 dst=192.168.3.10 sport=4000 dport=80 zone-orig=100 src=192.168.2.10 dst=192.168.3.10 sport=80 dport=4000 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

Comment: Nice work! But I suspect that to avoid Netfilter thinking inner 192.168.2.2:2222 to outer 192.168.3.2:4444 is the same as outer 192.168.2.2:2222 to inner 192.168.3.2:4444 conntrack zones reflecting the topology have to be added in the ruleset. I wouldn't know before hand if --zone or --orig-zone should be used. Once zones are set, these two flows would be detected as two different flows. (rewrote the comment with a slightly simpler example with different ports)

Comment: @A.B Good catch! That didn't come up in testing because all of my test connections were using a randomized source port, so they always showed up as distinct connections. Take a look at the update I just made to the answer and let me know if that looks correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks fine (one source port got rewritten to avoid clash, so the reply side has a different destination). Yet I wonder if there's a way to have not this rewrite happening. Oh well. splitting too much hair.

Comment: Amazing work!

What if the Q was slightly different: There is no need for the two networks to see each other, but we need middleman itself to be able to talk to both! Added difficulty: The 'outer' network has a DHCP service that middleman needs to use. I guess we'd access the outer net unNATed as 192.168.2.0/24, and NETMAP only the inner to 192.168.3.0/24. 

BTW this is not an academic question - I have found myself repeatedly facing this conundrum.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely well-written answer. I was finally able to implement it in my environment, but am coming across an issue. When icmp-packets return (echo-replies), they go straight from the raw (mangle) prerouting straight to the raw prerouting for the vrf-outer interface. This even with the packet being marked with notrack for conntrack. How can I diagnose why the packet is skipping the nat prerouting chain when it enters middleman-eth1? I am using nftables and the nftrace is turned on for all chains, and all chains except for those I defined have been deleted.

Comment: That's probably worth opening a new question, because I'd want to see the complete nftables ruleset. If you want to open the question and post it link to it here I'd be happy to take a look. How have you dealt with the lack of `NETMAP` support in nftables?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for my late answers, I only work one day per week but try to reply as fast as possible. I will create a new question this Friday when I work, but the lack of netmap support was solved by creating nftables-maps and doing lookups in them.

Comment: I have finally opened a new question, but with some slight clarifications and modifications from here. I have tried to modify this config to work as I want, but am still struggling with a few parts. The new question can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740854/routing-between-identical-copies-of-network-with-assymetric-ips-on-bridge-machin @larsks