# Routing between identical copies of network with assymetric IPs on bridge machine

Tags: linux, networking, nftables

Given the following:

One host called middleman has the interfaces:

| Interface | Address | Location | Master VRF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| enp1s0 | 192.168.2.99 | Outer network | vrf-outer |
| enp2s0 | 192.168.2.1 | Inner network | vrf-inner |

Presume that the outer network has default gateway 192.168.2.1, and that we have another network - 192.168.3.0/24.
If we have machine 192.168.2.22 on the outer network, and a machine with the same ip on the inner network, we use the 192.168.3.0/24-network to enable them to talk to each other. If host 192.168.2.22 on the outer network wants to contact 192.168.2.22 on the inner network we use the ip 192.168.3.22. This gets transported to enp1s0, dstnat:ed, routed via vrf-outer, srcnat:ed and routed to the correct machine through enp2s0. The response then takes the same path using conntrack nat on the way back.

I currently have this working somewhat using a modified config from the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735931/routing-traffic-to-virtual-copy-of-network-without-namespaces) , but cannot ssh 192.168.2.99 from a machine on the outer network. Instead, I get a "connection refused" from the vrf-outer (found through wireshark). Pinging 192.168.2.99 from the same machine works, and all communications between machines on the inner network and the outer network (as well as the internet) works.

The packet flow is as follows with the command `ssh 192.168.2.99` is executed on host 192.168.2.234 on the outer network:

1. outer host -> enp1s0 (192.168.234 -> 192.168.2.99) [SYN]
2. enp1s0 -> vrf-outer (192.168.234 -> 192.168.2.99) [SYN]
3. vrf-outer -> enp1s0 (192.168.99 -> 192.168.2.234) [RST, ACK]
4. enp1s0 -> outer host (192.168.99 -> 192.168.2.234) [RST, ACK]

`conntrack -L` shows no trace of this connection, and `nft monitor trace` shows nothing but `verdict accept` for all rules. Firewalld is configured to allow ssh on all interfaces and zones.

The configuration I am using is included below. Thank you for your time!

```
#!/bin/bash
TW_INT="vrf-tw-int"
TW_EXT="vrf-tw-ext"
EXT="enp1s0"
INT="enp2s0"
 
 
DESIRED_ZONE="FedoraServer"
 
 
############################### SET ECHO COMMAND WHEN EXECUTING ###################################
set -x
 
 
############################### ENABLE IP-FORWARDING ##############################################
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
 
 
############################### REMOVE OLD VRF INTERFACES #########################################
nmcli con del ${TW_INT} || true
nmcli con del ${TW_EXT} || true
 
 
############################### ADD VRF INTERFACES ################################################
nmcli con add type vrf con-name ${TW_INT} ifname ${TW_INT} table 100 ipv4.method disabled ipv6.method disabled
nmcli con add type vrf con-name ${TW_EXT} ifname ${TW_EXT} table 200 ipv4.method disabled ipv6.method disabled
 
 
############################### SET VRF INTERFACES UP #############################################
nmcli con up ${TW_INT}
nmcli con up ${TW_EXT}
 
 
############################### ADD VRF INTERFACES TO ACTUAL INTERFACES ###########################
nmcli con mod ${INT} master ${TW_INT}
nmcli con mod ${EXT} master ${TW_EXT}
 
nmcli con up ${INT}
nmcli con up ${EXT}
 
 
############################### ADD IP-ADDRESSES ##################################################
nmcli con mod ${INT} ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.1/24
 
nmcli con mod ${INT} ipv4.method manual
 
nmcli con up ${INT}
ip route show table 100
ip route show table 200
ip route
 
 
############################### MOVE INTERFACES IN FIREWALLD AND SET FORWARD ######################
ZONE_INT=$(firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=${INT})
ZONE_EXT=$(firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=${EXT})
ZONE_TW_INT=$(firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=${TW_INT})
ZONE_TW_EXT=$(firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=${TW_EXT})
 
firewall-cmd --zone=${DESIRED_ZONE} --add-forward                --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${ZONE_INT}     --remove-interface ${INT}    --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${ZONE_EXT}     --remove-interface ${EXT}    --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${ZONE_TW_INT}  --remove-interface ${TW_INT} --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${ZONE_TW_EXT}  --remove-interface ${TW_EXT} --permanent
 
firewall-cmd --zone=${DESIRED_ZONE} --add-interface ${INT}    --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${DESIRED_ZONE} --add-interface ${EXT}    --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${DESIRED_ZONE} --add-interface ${TW_INT} --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=${DESIRED_ZONE} --add-interface ${TW_EXT} --permanent
 
firewall-cmd --reload
 
ip addr
 
 
############################### ADD CONNTRACK LABELS ##############################################
mkdir -p /etc/xtables
cat << EOF > /etc/xtables/connlabel.conf
1 INSIDE
2 OUTSIDE
EOF
ln -s /etc/xtables/connlabel.conf /etc/connlabel.conf
ln -s /etc/xtables/connlabel.conf /etc/nftables/connlabel.conf
 
 
############################### ADD ROUTING RULES FOR MARKED PACKETS ##############################
ip rule add prio 100 fwmark 100 lookup 200
ip rule add prio 200 fwmark 200 lookup 100
 
 
############################### ADD DEFAULT ROUTE FOR MACHINE #####################################
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev ${EXT}
 
 
############################### FIX VRF ROUTE SOURCES #############################################
ip route del 192.168.2.0/24 dev ${EXT} proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.99 metric 105 table 200 || true
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev ${EXT} proto kernel scope link metric 105 table 200 || true
 
ip route del default via 192.168.2.1 dev ${EXT} proto dhcp src 192.168.2.99 metric 105 table 200 || true
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev ${EXT} proto dhcp metric 105 table 200 || true
 
ip route del 192.168.2.0/24 dev ${INT} proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 metric 106 table 100 || true
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev ${INT} proto kernel scope link metric 106 table 100 || true
 
 
############################### ADD TABLES AND FLUSH OLD TABLES ###################################
nft 'add table ip twilight'
nft 'delete table ip twilight'
 
nft 'add table ip twilight'
 
 
############################### ADD PREROUTING CHAINS #############################################
nft 'add chain ip twilight prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept; }'
 
 
############################### ADD PREROUTING MANGLE CHAINS ######################################
nft 'add chain ip twilight premangle { type filter hook prerouting priority -180; policy accept; }'
 
 
############################### ADD RAW (PRE-CONNTRACK) CHAINS ####################################
nft 'add chain ip twilight raw { type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept; }'
 
 
############################### ADD POSTROUTING CHAINS ############################################
nft 'add chain ip twilight postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept; }'
 
 
############################### ADD FORWARDING CHAINS #############################################
nft 'add chain ip twilight forward { type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept; }'
 
 
############################### ADD EXTERNAL TRANSLATION MAPS #####################################
nft 'add map ip twilight from_192_168_3_0_to_192_168_2_0 { type ipv4_addr: ipv4_addr; }'
 
 
############################### ADD INTERNAL TRANSLATION MAPS #####################################
nft 'add map ip twilight from_192_168_2_0_to_192_168_3_0 { type ipv4_addr: ipv4_addr; }'
 
 
############################### ADD DEBUG RULES FOR ALL PACKETS ###################################
nft 'add rule ip twilight prerouting  meta nftrace set 1'
nft 'add rule ip twilight postrouting meta nftrace set 1'
nft 'add rule ip twilight forward     meta nftrace set 1'
nft 'add rule ip twilight raw         meta nftrace set 1'
nft 'add rule ip twilight premangle   meta nftrace set 1'
 
 
############################### ADD DNAT RULES ####################################################
nft 'add rule ip twilight prerouting ip daddr 192.168.3.0/24 meta nftrace set 1 dnat to ip daddr map @from_192_168_3_0_to_192_168_2_0'
 
 
############################### ADD ROUTING RULES - MARK PACKETS ##################################
nft "add rule ip twilight raw          iif "${INT}" ip daddr 192.168.3.0/24    meta mark set 100"
nft "add rule ip twilight raw          iif "${EXT}" ip daddr 192.168.3.0/24    meta mark set 200"
nft "add rule ip twilight prerouting   iif "${INT}" ip daddr != 192.168.3.0/24 ct label set INSIDE"
nft "insert rule ip twilight premangle iif "${EXT}" ct label INSIDE meta mark set 200"
 
 
############################### TELL CONNTRACK ORIGINAL ZONES FOR MARKED PACKETS ##################
nft "add rule ip twilight raw iif "${INT}" ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.2.0/24 ct original zone set 100"
nft "add rule ip twilight raw iif "${EXT}" ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.2.0/24 ct original zone set 200"
 
 
############################### ADD SNAT RULES ####################################################
nft 'add rule ip twilight postrouting ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.2.0/24 meta nftrace set 1 snat to ip saddr map @from_192_168_2_0_to_192_168_3_0'
 
 
############################### ADD TWILIGHT -> WORLD MASQUERADE ##################################
nft "add rule ip twilight postrouting iif "${TW_INT}" oif "${EXT}" ip daddr != 192.168.2.0/24 meta nftrace set 1 masquerade"
 
 
############################### ADD TWILIGHT -> REGLER FORWARDING #################################
nft "add rule ip twilight forward iif "${INT}"    meta nftrace set 1 accept"
nft "add rule ip twilight forward iif "${TW_EXT}" meta nftrace set 1 accept"
nft "add rule ip twilight forward oif "${INT}"    meta nftrace set 1 accept"
 
 
############################### ADD REGLER -> TWILIGHT FORWARDING #################################
nft "add rule ip twilight forward iif "${EXT}" ip daddr 192.168.3.0/24 meta nftrace set 1 accept"
 
 
############################### ADD ELEMENTS TO INTERNAL TRANSLATION MAP ##########################
nft 'include "/etc/nftables/nft-host-alias-twilight-192.168.2.0-192.168.3.0"'
 
 
############################### ADD ELEMENTS TO EXTERNAL TRANSLATION MAP ##########################
nft 'include "/etc/nftables/nft-host-alias-twilight-192.168.3.0-192.168.2.0"'
 
 
############################### MAKE FIREWALLD IGNORE TWILIGHT TRAFFIC ############################
FIREWALLD_CHAINS="mangle_PREROUTING nat_PREROUTING nat_POSTROUTING nat_OUTPUT filter_PREROUTING filter_INPUT filter_FORWARD filter_OUTPUT"
for CHAIN in ${FIREWALLD_CHAINS}; do 
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${TW_INT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${TW_EXT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${EXT}"    oif "${INT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${EXT}"    ip daddr 192.168.3.0/24 accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${EXT}"    oif "${TW_INT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${EXT}"    oif "${TW_EXT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${INT}"    oif "${EXT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${INT}"    ip daddr 192.168.221.0/24 accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${INT}"    oif "${TW_INT}" accept"
  nft "insert rule inet firewalld "${CHAIN}" iif "${INT}"    oif "${TW_EXT}" accept"
done
```

Comment: Please don't include pastebin links in your question; the question becomes much less useful to future readers if the pastebin link expires.

Comment: Of course! I feared that the code was much too long to have in the question, but I'll think about that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config showed above works as intended, with one small caveat. Vrf interfaces include vrf contexts, to handle multi-tennant applications. This means that applications can be vrf-aware and only listen to a specific vrf context, where all programs run in a default vrf context unless told otherwise. My traffic was being routed to the vrf-outer context, and thus the traffic was dropped as there was no ssh server listening to that vrf context.

You can make programs that listen to the default vrf context work across all contexts by running:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_l3mdev_accept=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.udp_l3mdev_accept=1
```

as documented in [the kernel documentation for vrf interfaces](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/vrf.html).

The same does not seem to apply for ipv6 as this has no l3mdev_accept options. It has not yet become clear to me as to exactly why ipv6 does not need this.